# Anydesk remote server display not supported e.g Wayland

Tags: 18.04

I downloaded Anydesk (4.0.1 64bit) on both my laptop and desktop and when I run it from one pc and try to connect to the other I get the following error

> remote server display not supported e.g Wayland.

Both PCs are running Ubuntu 18.04.2.
I tried search for a solution, I found a suggestion to disable Wayland in the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` 
setting `WaylandEnable=false` but nothing changed.

Comment: WaylandEnable=false worked for me after reboot

Comment: `WaylandEnable=false` was enough for me after reboot, but then when I logged in, the session crashed, however when I restarted client and connected again it worked and I was connected to the already logged-in screen :-)

Answer (score 63):

After installing Anydesk on my Ubuntu 18.04 server and trying to connect from a Mac, I would get a `display_server_not_supported` error. I was able to resolve this by going into the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file and changing:

```
[daemon]
    # Enabling automatic login
    AutomaticLoginEnable=true
    AutomaticLogin=$USERNAME
```

After rebooting the Ubuntu server, Anydesk now connects and shows the login screen and I can login just fine.

Comment: For anyone coming across this answer, don't forget to also put `WaylandEnable=false` in the config as the question-asker mentioned. Both are required.

Comment: I'm running manjaro and still have the issue. Anyone help?

Comment: Solution: Change to Xorg/X11. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/i-cant-share-my-screen/40586/3 Reboot PC, choose Xorg in login screen.

Comment: setting up a password, with: echo "xxxxx | sudo anydesk --set-password, UN-comenting WaylandEnable=false, adding the corrections above and reboot, solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem connecting Anydesk Windows 7 to Anydesk UBUNTU.
At some point Ubuntu and Wayland started from some cause. As you wrote WaylandEnable = false did not help. It helped me to opt out of the user and when I sign in before I confirm the password, choose (under the gear) only pure Ubuntu without Wayland.
You can try if it also works for you.

Comment: hmm thanks for your reply. I use a multiuser setup with i3wm instead of Ubuntu desktop so I don't have this gear option to suppress wayland. 
I have to do it with some configuration parameters I guess (for example inside .xsession file) and don't know how!