# Ubuntu 18.04 - Black screen after login and unable to get into console

Tags: boot, 18.04, login, wayland

Good afternoon everyone!

I was trying to remotely access my computer through AnyDesk. I faced some issues and I followed the steps on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131921/anydesk-remote-server-display-not-supported-e-g-wayland) trying to solve the problem. After uncommenting `WaylandEnable = false` on the **custom.conf** file, I was able to remotely login on my user but the screen is fully black and I'm unable to access the console through `ctrl+alt+f1` or similar combinations. I'm able to reboot thorugh AnyDesk and access the Windows partition normally, but the problem persists on Ubuntu and I'm not able to restore the **custom.conf** file to its original state to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf after a normal Ubuntu login, or via Recovery Mode... but I don't think that will make any difference to your situation. When you login, after selecting your username, click the cogwheel icon and tell me what your choices are, and which one is selected.