# How to start AnyDesk in Ubuntu using command prompt

Tags: xubuntu, remote-desktop, reboot, remote-access

I am using my remote desktop via AnyDesk and I have rebooted my remote Ubuntu machine.

Now I want to launch AnyDesk using the command line prompt to access the remote machine using the AnyDesk app.

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 (both client and remote)

Kill anydesk

```
sudo killall anydesk
```

Start the anydesk service

```
sudo anydesk --service
```

Source: https://support.anydesk.com/Command_Line_Interface

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this:

```
sudo systemctl start anydesk
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Update Ubuntu System**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y upgrade
```

**Step 2: Add AnyDesk repository**

```
wget -qO - https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -


echo "deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list
```

**Step 3: Install AnyDesk on Ubuntu 20.04/18.04 LTS**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install anydesk
```

**Step 4: Launch AnyDesk on Ubuntu 20.04/18.04**

```
$ anydesk
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, fixed the issue using this, [Anydesk remote server display not supported e.g Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/q/1131921/348964)

```
vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Edit the following lines with `$USERNAME` as your Ubuntu username;

```
[daemon]
    # Enabling automatic login
    AutomaticLoginEnable=true
    AutomaticLogin=$USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just enter `anydesk` then once the client is launched enter the id and password of machine which you want to connect to .

Here is a list of the available command if you want to stay on the command prompt https://support.anydesk.com/Command_Line_Interface

Comment: above command line interface for windows machine but i have UBUNTU16.04 OS for UBUNTU os any command please suggest..