# Launch Anydesk from dedicated CLI to get GUI access to a system

Tags: command-line, gui

I am using Anydesk to remotely access my workstation. I would like to be able to launch it via CLI in Ubuntu (if stuck for example or if it consumes too much memory). I have access to CLI, but if I try the obvious:

```
$anydesk &
```

I get the following messages:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display
```

Since the same command seems to work from a GUI CLI emulator it probably has to do with the fact that I am trying to launch a GUI application from a CLI. Is there a way to achieve this somehow, or is it a deadend? I mean I need a GUI environment to launch a GUI application at the first case, so it seems like a vicious circle.

I know a workaround would be to reboot my system and anydesk will be automatically restarted (and hopefully it will be more functional than before the restart) but I was hoping for a more direct solution.

Comment: if you are first connected remotely to the workstation with ssh and write on terminal anydesk &, anydesk wont open because it has GUI.. you can try also touch example.txt and sudo gedit example.txt you will get an error --> cannot open display because gedit has also a GUI..

Comment: So, the answer is that I cannot launch GUI applications remotely from ssh?

Comment: Im looking for the same and I found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh.. It looks like it's possible, but you can give it a try ...

Comment: Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/a/1311072/775359